# "were" or "were staying"

Tags: sentence-construction, difference

> Mrs. Smith was busy last weekend because her grandchildren were staying with her.

Can we say "Mrs. Smith was busy last weekend because her grandchildren were with her." -without "staying" ?

Comment: _Staying with her_ means that they were sleeping at her house over the weekend. _With her_ just means that they were in her company; it could be understood as implying that they were staying there, but doesn't actually say so.

Comment: You could even say *Mrs. Smith was busy last weekend with her grandchildren …* (The fact that they were staying with her is simply additional information. They could have been baking a cake, watching a movie, or doing any number of other things that kept her busy.)